# how to run multiple ccAnimation in one ccSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have one character sprite and i have to run multiple ccAnimation on it like run animation and jump animation. For this i have created spritesheet and assign it the frames. here is my code:

```
 [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"ch_run_slow.plist"];


    spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"ch_run_slow.png"];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];

    _character = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Ch_run_slow_12.png"];

    _character.tag=1;


    [spriteSheet addChild:_character];
```

and my animation functions are:

```
-(void) characterSlowRun

{
      NSMutableArray *runSlowAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=1; i<=12; i++)
{

    [runSlowAnimFrames addObject:
     [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ch_run_slow_%d.png",i]]];

}


CCAnimation *runSlow = [CCAnimation
                          animationWithSpriteFrames:runSlowAnimFrames delay:0.1f];

runSlowAction=[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:runSlow];
runSlowAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
   [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:runSlow]];
[_character runAction:runSlowAction];



}
```

and Jump Action method is:

```
-(void) characterJumpSmall
{

[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFramesFromFile:@"ch_run_slow.plist"];


[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"ch_jump_small.plist"];

spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"ch_jump_small.png"];

NSMutableArray *jumpSmallAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=1; i<=13; i++)
{

    [jumpSmallAnimFrames addObject:
     [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ch_jump_small_%d.png",i]]];

}
CCAnimation *jumpSmall = [CCAnimation
                        animationWithSpriteFrames:jumpSmallAnimFrames delay:0.1f];

jumpSmallAction=[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:jumpSmall];

[_character runAction:jumpSmallAction];

}
```

on init i call [self characterSlowRun]; and on ccTouchesEnded i use [_character stopAction:runSlowAction];
        [self characterJumpSmall];
initially runSlow action works fine bt when tap on screen it crashes. jump action not working. what i do? please help me

Comment: post your crash log and 'ccTouchEnded:' method

Comment: here is my log                                                                                          *** Assertion failure in -[CCSprite setTexture:]

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop your walkSlow Action with `[_charactar stopAllActions]` because walkSlow is running endlessly.

Comment: i did it in ccTouchesEnded                                       [_character stopAction:runSlowAction];

Answer (score 0):

`Assertion failure in -[CCSprite setTexture:]`. And that's all? I am sure that your error message is a bit longer. Also you can check cocos2d sources, as it is open source and see what line caused this assertion failure.

Anyway, it seems that your touble is just a result of trying to use frames from different spritesheets on a single sprite. Place your animations to a single spritesheet and it should work fine.

Comment: Here is full log                                                          *** Assertion failure in -[CCSprite setTexture:], libs/cocos2d/CCSprite.m:941
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class 'nil'
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: and what about placing all the animation frames in the same spritesheet?